How does an AC of 5100W (1.5 ton) capacity work without any issue with 1000W of total electricity load of my house?
I have one AC of 5100W (1.5 ton) capacity and I generally run it along with other appliances like fans, LED bulbs, TV and more. My house is sanctioned 1000W of load which is mentioned in my electricity bill. Still it work without any issue.
I did some research for that and came to know that 5100W is thermal heat units and electrical load of 1.5 TR (tons of Refrigeration) is about 1800 watt approximately. Still it is well under the total load of my house which is 1kW. How can it work?
How is it possible? Am I still misunderstanding something?

But 1800 W is more than 1kW. Your house can't be 1kW. My water kettle is more than 2 kW, my vacuum cleaner is about 1 kW and my desktop computer has a 1kW power supply if I recall. What are you sanctioned?

The 5100 W number is how much heat the air conditioner can move. That's the critical thing here--an air conditioner moves heat, which takes less energy than producing heat, so you can move 5 kW while consuming only about 1 to 2 kW.
Then there's the simple fact that your air conditioner is not running 24/7 (if it is, you have an undersized AC and should replace it--the compressor will wear out in no time if it runs continuously). It might move 5100 W of heat and consume 1800 W of electricity while it's running, but it will only be running maybe 15 minutes out of every hour--the average power is much less.
I'll also note that 1 kW for an entire house is a very low number--are you sure about that? Is that maybe an instantaneous power measurement at some point where not much is running? Your average microwave oven consumes more than 1 kW when running, all on its own--it's hard to believe that an entire house would never use more than 1 kW total.

We have not ran two ACs simultaneously, neither a microwave. We have ran one AC simultaneously with bulbs and fans only..

It might mean that wiring size of house is good but my electric meter is running overloaded. Since there is no much difference of meter size for lower and higher capacity that is why it is working.
